# Identify the distribution of data

Tags: r, normal-distribution, repeated-measures, poisson-distribution, repeatability

I did one experiment two times with the same subject. I want to find the repeatability of my result. repeatability in a sense is the fraction of behavioural variation that is due to differences between individuals.

Formally, repeatability is r = s A 2 s 2 + s A 2 where s A 2 is the variance among individuals and s2 is the variance within individuals over time.

I want to perform repeatability analysis in r from the following method method:https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/rptR/vignettes/rptR.html

To do the analysis I want to finalize the type of distribution. please help me to identify my distribution (named as trail value) my data https://1drv.ms/x/s!AjkB79YfRWo3j3wYTlXQCRRGZU55?e=V82wiA

Thanks in advance,